# Find all four-digit numbers with both a square and a cube root

Tags: calculus

How would one find *all* numbers that have at most 4 digits and have both a square and a cube root?

$$x\in\mathbb{I};0<x<10^{3}\\
\sqrt[2]{x}\in\mathbb{I}\\
\sqrt[3]{x}\in\mathbb{I}$$

While this isn't a homework question I feel it's appropriate to be tagged as such as I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a number to be a square and a cube, it has to be a 6th power. (Can you see why?) Therefore the answer is every 6th power from $0$ to $9999$. This is $1^6, 2^6, 3^6, 4^6$.

Comment: Thank you, as with many problems, once someone has laid an explanation out it seems very easy and obvious.